# virtualize BS2000/Posix or z/OS

Tags: virtualization, zos

Is it possible to create a virtual instance of either BS2000/Posix or z/OS on libvirt KVM, or any other virtualization platform?
I have been asked to provide this so that software can be tested within these environments.

Answer (score 1):

z/OS can be run on the [Hercules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_emulator) mainframe emulator, but it is probably not allowed by your IBM licensing terms.  The [Hercules FAQ](http://www.hercules-390.org/hercfaq.html#2.01) briefly discusses this issue.

I'm not sure about BS2000 nor have I used it, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS2000) claims that it's been ported to x86, so that version should be able to run on some virtualization platform.  If the usual suspects don't work, I would try Bochs or QEMU.  They can be run as full emulators which means that they [support operating systems such as OS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2#Virtualization) that use the stranger features of the x86 architecture that more mainstream virtualization platforms may not take the time to properly implement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll look into that all (making sure to keep an eye on the licensing)